# Is it possible to achieve 100% steam achievements without spending money?

Tags: steam, achievements, path-of-exile

Do I need any additional content packs or DLCs which are not part of the F2P part of Path of Exile to achieve 100% Steam achievements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only pay parts of Path of Exile are cosmetic microtransactions which have no effect on gameplay and thus no effect on achievements.